# InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression contains(text() error message

Tags: selenium, dynamics-crm

I'm getting this error message when selenium/C# program tried to click on an element in a drop down list in Dynamis365.

*Inner Exception 1:
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression contains(text(), 'Submitted') because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)*

My Code is:

```
  internal void SetValues()
    {
        findByElement.FindByXPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Submission Pending')]").Click();
        findByElement.FindByXPath("contains(text(), 'Submitted')").Click();
    }
```

The HTML is:

```
<span id="id-bc19d003-2d6a-43ad-8e1b-566ecbb00647-132-statuscode6-statuscode.fieldControl-pickliststatus-comboBox_text-value" class=" ">Submission Pending</span>
```

I'm trying to click on *Submitted* choice, which do not show in HTML:[DropDownList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUKz.png)

**Note:** The other drop down list choices do not show in html. Only after making a choice (*Submitted*) it shows up in the html (replaces Submission Pending")
[*Submission Pending*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiQki.png)
[*Submitted* clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ruf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line of code worked:

**findByElement.FindByXPath("//*[./text()='Submitted']").Click();**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the page has fully loaded?  Have you read the docs, specifically the 'waits' section (link below for the python version). I had this problem and simply put a 5 second delay into the code and it worked fine.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Alternatively you may find it easier locating the element by id rather than by XPath

Comment: The page was fully loaded (used an explicit wait) and the Id is dynamic in Dynamics365, therefore can not search by it. Issue is to click on *Submitted* menu choice and unable to do that. I've done similar at another place in the same program and it works, but not here.

Answer (score 0):

```
FindByXPath("contains(text(), 'Submitted')")
```

This is not a valid XPath expression! All XPath must start with the slash `/` character. Perhaps you meant something like:

```
FindByXPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Submitted')]")
```

Comment: I tried all of these and still no luck. I've added a note to the original questions with screen shots of html, before and after.

Comment: Screenshots of code/text are not useful. If the elements are not immediately present in the DOM, you will have to use waits.

Comment: Would you be able to help how to find if the element is present in the DOM? I'm using ELementIsVisible(By). Also have tried ElementExists(By), ElementToBeClickable(By) and no luck.

Comment: Without me having access to your DOM, plus this platform, is not an ideal situation to debug a problem. I personally try to identify broader chunks of the DOM by XPath, verify they are unique and present, and then narrow things down from there. Often the application is responsive - you may have to resort to (multiple!?!?) waits. This can be discovered with sufficient debugging.